# Table and Query optimization

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

Simple web app, hosted on standard shared hosting using PHp and MySql backend.

I have two relatively small tables (few hundred rows in each) that when I query with a join the query can take two to three seconds.

Here's one table:  'students':

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
`_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `dateOfBirth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `knownasname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `school` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `schoolyear` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `foundusvia` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateadded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `archived` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `_id` (`_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=684 ;
```

Here's the second:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `studentAddressStreet` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studentAddressArea` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studentAddressTown` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studentAddressPostcode` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studentPhoneMobile` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studentPhoneLand` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studentAddressNotes` text,
  `studentemail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingAddressStreet` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingAddressArea` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingAddressTown` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingAddressPostcode` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingPhoneMobile` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingPhoneLand` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingContactName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingContactRelationship` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingAddressNotes` text,
  `billingemail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverAddressStreet` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverAddressArea` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverAddressTown` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverAddressPostcode` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverPhoneMobile` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverPhoneLand` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverContactName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverContactRelationship` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiverAddressNotes` text,
  `caregiveremail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  KEY `contacts_index` (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=290 ;
```

Here's the query:

Its job is to get all the data from the table "students' and 'contacts' for the student with a given _id.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM students, contacts
 WHERE students._id = contacts.student_id
  AND students._id =99  <=== This value obviously changes
```

The table `contacts` has an index on student_id

The table students has an index on firstname and lastname.

What is wrong to make this query take 2 to 3 seconds to run?  The tables are small and the query simple.   Any help greatly appreciated!!

edit:  here's the output of EXPLAIN.  Also revised CREATE for contacts table

```
id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
===|=============|=========|======|===============|==============|=========|======|=============
1  |  SIMPLE     | students|const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY      |  3      |const | 1    |
1  |  SIMPLE     | contacts|ref   | contacts_index|contacts_index|  3      |const | 1    |
```

Comment: Create an index in the `contacts` table over `(student_id)`.

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` additionally. Btw `UNIQUE KEY `_id` (`_id`)` is redundant

Comment: SELECT only the columns you want. Join using proper JOIN syntax. And place an index on contacts.student_id

Comment: @zerkms I suspect that stuff is generated by the application.

Comment: You say that "*The table `contacts` has an index on student_id*", but it's not shown in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Yep, there is an index on contacts.student_id.  It's not shown in the create table - my bad - I created the index after I  grabbed the text for create table.  Adding the index made no discernible difference.  Newb question - when an index is added does it take time for the server to build the index?  In other words will I see the effect immediately?

Comment: @MarkNZ: It does take time, but is complete once the DDL command that creates the index returns.  Could you let us see the updated `CREATE TABLE` statement, please?  And also, like @zerkms asked, the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`?

Comment: Apologies for the delay.  I've updated the original question with the CREATE for contacts with the index and with the EXPLAIN for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip: If at all possible avoid `SELECT *`. It's especially problematic on JOINs.

You'll have an easier time reading your query if you use a standard JOIN, like so. That comma-separated list of tables [jumped the shark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_the_shark) sometime in the late 1990s.

```
SELECT students.*, 
       contacts.* 
  FROM students
  LEFT JOIN contacts ON students._id = contacts.student_id
 WHERE students._id =99
```

Finally, put an index on the `student_id` column of the `contacts` table so the join can quickly access that table.

Comment: Thanks.  I kinda need all the columns hence the "select * ".  Will try a JOIN instead.  There is an index on contacts.student_id already (see my comment above).

Comment: @marknz Seeing as both tables share a column, that cannot be true!